# Python TypeError: .__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given , problem with super()

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, super

I am facing a TypeError for the below code:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name,age,subject):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.subject = subject

    def subjchoosen(self):
        print("The subject choosen is",self.subject )

class Science(Student):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(name, age,subject)
        super().subjchoosen()

name = "Test"
age = 12
subject = "Science"
Sc=Science(name,age,subject)
```

If I am creating the object as `Sc= Science()` without passing any arguments I will get the output. Can someone please explain why this happens?

Comment: You didn't define `Science.__init__` to take any arguments. It doesn't *guess* that it should accept more just because you are calling `super().__init__` in the body of the function.

Comment: Ignoring the fact that `Science` should probably not be subclassing `Student` in the first place, see https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ for advice on not having to duplicate parent `__init__` parameters in a child `__init__`.

Comment: Calling `Science()` means `Science.__init__` is looking for *global* variables named `name`, `age`, and `subject`, which you happened to define. That's not a good way to design a class, however.

Comment: There's no need to use `super` to invoke `subjchoosen`, since you didn't override the function. Just use `self.subjchoosen()` and let attribute lookup find the inherited method.

Answer (score 1):

You have to also put `name, age, subject` arguments into the `__init__` method of `Science` class, since now it only expects self.

Correct way would be:

```
class Science(Student):
     def __init__(self, name, age, subject):
         super().__init__(name, age,subject)
         super().subjchoosen()
```

Comment: quoting @chepner There's no need to use super to invoke subjchoosen, since you didn't override the function. Just use self.subjchoosen() and let attribute lookup find the inherited method. – 
c